# Saltstack ssh failure on running salt state.apply

Tags: salt-stack

The salt master version is 3002.6
The salt minion version is 3002.9
Salt key is getting generated successfully in master. But while running salt state.apply
, I am getting the below error.

[DEBUG   ] Trying to connect to: tcp://XX.XX.XX.XX:4506
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_pub_key: Loading public key
[ERROR   ] Sign-in attempt failed: {'enc': 'pub', 'pub_key': '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n', 'publish_port': 4505, 'aes':[DEBUG   ] Closing AsyncZeroMQReqChannel instance

I checked the network as well as firewall. I checked as per the link below.

https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/troubleshooting/minion.html

Everything is fine from servers' end. Direct ssh between the salt and the master is also working.
As per a suggestion in the below forum, the master has to be higher in version than minions and should be upgraded before minions.

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/61867

Is that the only reason for such errors?
Do I need to check something else other that version upgrade ?
Because, as I have mentioned earlier salt master and minion versions are same, but minor version of minion is higher than master.  (master 3002.6, minion 3002.9)
The salt master is running in RHEL7 whereas salt minion is running in RHEL8.

Comment: "the master has to be higher in version than minions and should be upgraded before minions" - that is the problem. Also all 3002.x are out of support.

Answer (score 0):

Salt version upgrade is the resolution for the above.